# Google Kubernetes Engine - Insufficient Quota to Run Application

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am attempting to deploy an image to a GKE cluster in GCP. I get this error message when I attempt to deploy my image:

Error creating a deployment
Insufficient regional quota to satisfy request: resource "SSD_TOTAL_GB": request requires '300.0' and is short '50.0'. project has a quota of '250.0' with '250.0' available. View and manage quotas at https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?usage=USED&project=*****-*****-*****.

Can anyone help me resolve this? How do I increase my quota?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're getting indicates that the zone/region you're in has a limit of 250 GB and the quota is [exhausted](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/regional-clusters#pricing) now. In order to start up a cluster, you need at least 300 GB and I guess this is why we're seeing the requirement going to 300GB where the disk-size defaults to 100GB.

As mentioned in the Google official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/pricing):

> To deliver a better default price-performance for applications, all GKE Autopilot clusters with control plane version 1.27.5 and later will use an SSD-based persistent disk for ephemeral storage. This change will only affect newly created clusters and new pods created in clusters upgraded to version 1.27.5 and later.

Hence try changing the default [SSD disk to a Standard Persistent Disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/performance) and it might help you in overcoming the issue.

You can also read more about the type of disk quotas [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/resource-usage#disk_quota) and how to increase the [quota limit](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota/view-manage).